# making table cell active using ng-click with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

**Problem:**
I have a table and a clickable `<td>`. What I want to happen is when I clicked on any of the following `<td>` It will become active but I can't do it right.

**DOM**

```
<table class="table-position">
  <tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <td ng-repeat="j in [1,2,3]" ng-click="selectPosition(j)" 
     ng-class="{active: selectedPosition == j}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**Directive**

```
$scope.selectPosition = function(position){
  $scope.selectedPosition = position;
}
```

**Text Render**

```
i1-[j1,j2,j3]
i2-[j1,j2,j3]
i3-[j1,j2,j3]
```

**Current Output:** This is the current output when I'm clicking on any of the ff: `<td>`[i1,j1],[i2,j1],[i3,j1]

[image]

**Expected Output:**
This is the expected output when I clicked on the center `<td>` [i2,j2]

[image]

I already tried to pass array and object on the `selectPosition` function but still not working. Not sure If I'm doing it right.

Please let me know if something is not clear. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/28nst1ga/)**

```
<table class="table-position" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
        <td ng-repeat="j in [1,2,3]" ng-click="selectPosition($parent.$index, $index)"
            ng-class="{active: (selectedPosition.parent == $parent.$index && selectedPosition.index == $index )}">{{ j }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Pass $index and $parent.$index when td is clicked.

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller("myCtrl", function ($scope) {

    $scope.selectPosition = function ($parentIndex, $index) {
        $scope.selectedPosition = {
            parent: $parentIndex,
            index: $index
        };
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you can make this prettier but the idea is that in your old code, the $scope.selectedPosition is always the same on each iteration of i, so naturally that j in each row gets active.

```
$scope.selectPosition = function(i, j){
  $scope.selectedPosition = {};
  $scope.selectedPosition.i = i;
  $scope.selectedPosition.j = j;
}

<table class="table-position">
  <tr ng-repeat="i in [1,2,3]">
    <td ng-repeat="j in [1,2,3]" ng-click="selectPosition(j)" 
     ng-class="{active: (selectedPosition.j == j && selectedPosition.i == i)}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```